# Can't figure out how to find library -lPods

Tags: swift, linker, mach-o

Library not found for -lPods! Can't figure out why it's not linking properly

'Ld /Users/joelwasserman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SyllaSync-cbjytqyyaytulbdwahjgpinpgktm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SyllaSync.app/SyllaSync normal arm64
    cd /Users/joelwasserman/SyllaSync/SyllaSync/SyllaSync
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.4
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.4.sdk -L/Users/joelwasserman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SyllaSync-cbjytqyyaytulbdwahjgpinpgktm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/joelwasserman/SyllaSync/SyllaSync/SyllaSync/Pods/Google/Libraries -L/Users/joelwasserman/SyllaSync/SyllaSync/SyllaSync/Pods/GoogleAppUtilities/Libraries -L/Users/joelwasserman/SyllaSync/SyllaSync/SyllaSync/Pods/GoogleAuthUtilities/Libraries -L/Users/joelwasserman/SyllaSync/SyllaSync/SyllaSync/Pods/GoogleNetworkingUtilities/Libraries -L/Users/joelwasserman/SyllaSync/SyllaSync/SyllaSync/Pods/GoogleSignIn/Libraries -L/Users/joelwasserman/SyllaSync/SyllaSync/SyllaSync/Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Libraries -L/Users/joelwasserman/SyllaSync/SyllaSync/SyllaSync/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Libraries -F/Users/joelwasserman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SyllaSync-cbjytqyyaytulbdwahjgpinpgktm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/joelwasserman/SyllaSync/SyllaSync/SyllaSync -F/Users/joelwasserman/SyllaSync/SyllaSync/SyllaSync/parse-library-1 -F/Users/joelwasserman/SyllaSync/SyllaSync/SyllaSync/FacebookSDK -filelist /Users/joelwasserman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SyllaSync-cbjytqyyaytulbdwahjgpinpgktm/Build/Intermediates/SyllaSync.build/Debug-iphoneos/SyllaSync.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SyllaSync.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -ObjC -lGGLCore -lGGLSignIn -lGIDExShared -lGSDK_Overload -lGTMOAuth2_external -lGTMOAuth2_internal -lGTMSessionFetcher_core -lGTMSessionFetcher_full -lGTMStackTrace -lGTM_AddressBook -lGTM_DebugUtils -lGTM_GTMURLBuilder -lGTM_KVO -lGTM_NSDictionary+URLArguments -lGTM_NSScannerJSON -lGTM_NSStringHTML -lGTM_NSStringXML -lGTM_Regex -lGTM_RoundedRectPath -lGTM_StringEncoding -lGTM_SystemVersion -lGTM_UIFont+LineHeight -lGTM_core -lGTM_iPhone -lOpenInChrome -lSignIn -framework AddressBook -framework CoreText -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/joelwasserman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SyllaSync-cbjytqyyaytulbdwahjgpinpgktm/Build/Intermediates/SyllaSync.build/Debug-iphoneos/SyllaSync.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SyllaSync.swiftmodule -miphoneos-version-min=8.4 -lstdc++.6 -framework Accounts -framework Social -lsqlite3 -framework FBSDKCoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework StoreKit -framework FBSDKShareKit -framework Security -framework FBSDKLoginKit -framework QuartzCore -framework MobileCoreServices -lz -framework CoreLocation -framework Bolts -framework CoreGraphics -framework CFNetwork -framework AudioToolbox -framework ParseCrashReporting -framework Parse -framework ParseUI -framework ParseFacebookUtilsV4 -lPods-SyllaSync -lPods -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/joelwasserman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SyllaSync-cbjytqyyaytulbdwahjgpinpgktm/Build/Intermediates/SyllaSync.build/Debug-iphoneos/SyllaSync.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SyllaSync_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/joelwasserman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SyllaSync-cbjytqyyaytulbdwahjgpinpgktm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SyllaSync.app/SyllaSync'

'ld: library not found for -lPods
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)'

Can't figure out how to find the library, i've tried cleaning, resetting my pods by reinstalling, and resetting to an older commit that previously compiled...

my podfile is as follows: 
' platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'SyllaSync' do

pod 'Google/SignIn'

end

target 'SyllaSyncTests' do

pod 'Google/SignIn'

end
'

UPDATE:

no previous commits or branches are working. every previously working branch and commit is now getting ld:Library not found for -lPods error

Comment: Usually it is because you are using library that does not have 64bit slice in your 64bit project ; Another thing can be that you are not running it from xcworkspace, but that seem unlikely because you already managed to run it. What did you change?

Comment: @JiriTrecak  deleted and imported SystemConfiguration.framework a few times because i was trying to use SCNetworkReachability and it was saying the identifier was unknown even though SystemConfiguration.framework was in my 'Link Binary With Libraries"

Comment: FIXED: in 'Link Binary With Libraries' removing libPods.a worked.